# UITextView inside UITableViewCell hides cursor when cell is selected

Tags: ios, uitableview, uitextview

I have `UITextView` subviews inside a `UITableViewCell`. When user taps on the cell I select it, i.e. I switch the background image to selected state. The `UITextView` becomes first responder, but the cursor is hidden. When I disable the cell selection the UITextView shows a cursor without issues.

How to select the cell and start editing the `UITextView` with a visible cursor? :)

```
- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];
    if (selected && ![textView isFirstResponder]) {
        [textView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
        [textView becomeFirstResponder];
    } else {
        [textView resignFirstResponder];
        [textView setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cell stopped to hide cursor, when i set.

```
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
```

But after that, cell also stopped use selectedBackgroundView. So I set my image to highlighted state of backgroundView.

```
cell.backgroundView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"input_up.png"] highlightedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"input_up_act.png"]] autorelease];
```

And switched image in setSelected:animated:

```
- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];
    if (selected && ![textView isFirstResponder]) {
        [textView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
        [textView becomeFirstResponder];
    } else {
        [textView resignFirstResponder];
        [textView setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
    }

    [(UIImageView *)self.backgroundView setHighlighted:selected];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

your cursor non disappeared maybe is't white! 
try: [self.tableView setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];

Answer (score 1):

You could try setting the `selected` property of `UITableViewCell` inside the `UITextViewDelegate` protocol method `textViewDidBeginEditing:`.

If this does not work, create a `UIImageView` as a subview of your cell and change the content of that in the method above.

Comment: that's was my first try. effect is the same. when cell is selected - cursor is hidden.

Comment: So I guess its a feature, not a bug. Why do you want to have the cell selected? See my edit for an alternative suggestion.

Comment: yes. probably it helps, but it not looks like a right solution. because i prefer to set styles for all my cells in the same way.

Answer (score 0):

When you select the cell, the textView become the first responder, but the cursor has been hidden, you can deselect the cell, and then the cursor will show.

Comment: yes. but cell should be selected while i'm edit text, because cell background image for selected state tell user:"hey there is text field and you're editing it now". :)